# Problemas con querySelectAll en Validaciones con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Desarrollando validaciones me tope con el problema que al momento de querer obtener el elemento `i` mediante `querySelectAll` me devuelve el `nodelist` vacío, pero solamente dentro de la función `validarFormulario` porque si saco el `console.log(document.querySelectAll('#Grupo__Usuario i'));` de la función si me arroja los elementos `i`

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById('#Formulario');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#Formulario input");

const expresiones = {
    usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{4,16}$/, // Letras, numeros, guion y guion_bajo
    nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
    password: /^.{4,12}$/, // 4 a 12 digitos.
    correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    telefono: /^\d{7,14}$/ // 7 a 14 numeros.
}

const validarFormulario = (e) => {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#Grupo__Usuario i'));
    switch (e.target.name) {
        case 'usuario':
            if (expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value)) {
                document.getElementById('Grupo__Usuario').classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
                document.getElementById('Grupo__Usuario').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
                console.log(document.querySelectorAll('#Grupo__Usuario i'));

            } else {
                document.getElementById('Grupo__Usuario').classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
            }
            break;

        case 'password':

            break;

        case 'password2':

            break;

        case 'correo':

            break;

        case 'telefono':

            break;
    }
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('keyup', validarFormulario);
    input.addEventListener('blur', validarFormulario);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-YSdqvJoZr83hj76AIVdOcvLWYMWzy6sJyIMic2aQz5kh2bPTd9dzY3NtdeEAzPp/PhgZqr4aJObB3ym/vsItMg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main>
<form id="Formulario" class="formulario">
    <!--Grupo Usuario-->
    <div id="Grupo__Usuario" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="usuario" class="formulario__label">Usuario</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="formulario__input" placeholder="Fernando123">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El usuario tiene que ser de 4 a 16 dígitos y solo puede contener numeros, letras y guion bajo</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Nombre-->
    <div id="Grupo__Nombre" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="nombre" class="formulario__label">Nombre</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="formulario__input" placeholder="John Doe">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El nombre tiene que ser de 4 a 16 dígitos y solo puede contener numeros, letras y guion bajo</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Contraseña-->
    <div id="Grupo__Password" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="password" class="formulario__label">Contraseña</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="formulario__input">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">La contraseña tiene que ser 4 a 12 digitos</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Contraseña-->
    <div id="Grupo__Password2" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="password2" class="formulario__label">Repetir Contraseña</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="formulario__input">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">Ambas contraseñas tienen que ser iguales</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Correo Electronico-->
    <div id="Grupo__Correo" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="correo" class="formulario__label">Correo Eléctronico</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" class="formulario__input" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El correo solo puede contener letras,numeros, punto y guines</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Telefono-->
    <div id="Grupo__Telefono" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="telefono" class="formulario__label">Telefono</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="formulario__input" placeholder="554589634">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El teléfono solo úede contener numeros y el máximo es de 14 dígitos
        </p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Terminos y Condiciones-->
    <div id="Grupo__Terminos" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label class="formulario__label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos" class="formulario__checkbox">
            Acepto los Terminos y Condiciones
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="formulario__mensaje" id="formulario__mensaje">
        <p>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><b>Error:</b> Por favor rellena el formulario correctamente
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">
        <button type="submit" class="formulario__btn">
            Enviar
        </button>
        <p class="formulario__mensaje-exito" id="formulario__mensaje-exito">
            Los datos se enviaron con éxito
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

El "problema" es que *fontawesome* comenta el elemento `<i>` y agrega un `<svg>`. Puedes comprobarlo haciendo clic derecho en el icono y seleccionando "Inspeccionar elemento".

¿Por qué funciona `console.log(document.querySelectAll('#Grupo__Usuario i'));` fuera de validación? Porque aún no se han cargado los scripts que realizan el remplazo de la etiqueta; sin embargo, al ejecutar la validación ya todo está cargado y las etiquetas fueron remplazadas.

Para modificar, solo hay que acceder por clase, pero buscando el div padre desde el elemento que disparó el evento y solo con `.querySelector()`, porque se trata de un icono nada más, no es necesario `.querySelectorAll()`.

```js
const formulario = document.getElementById('#Formulario');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#Formulario input");

const expresiones = {
    usuario: /^[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{4,16}$/, // Letras, numeros, guion y guion_bajo
    nombre: /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s]{1,40}$/, // Letras y espacios, pueden llevar acentos.
    password: /^.{4,12}$/, // 4 a 12 digitos.
    correo: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/,
    telefono: /^\d{7,14}$/ // 7 a 14 numeros.
}
// fa-times-circle a fa-check-circle
const validarFormulario = (e) => {
    // Obtener div padre por clase
    let padre = e.target.closest('div.formulario__grupo');
    // Obtener icono desde contenedor
    let icon = e.target.closest('div').querySelector('.formulario__validacion-estado');
    let test = false;
    switch (e.target.name) {
        case 'usuario':
            test = expresiones.usuario.test(e.target.value);
            break;

        case 'password':
            // Validar juntos
        case 'password2':
            if(document.querySelector('#password').value != document.querySelector('#password2').value) {
                // Las contraseñas no son iguales
                test = false;
            } else {
                test = expresiones.password.test(e.target.value);
            }
            // Actualizar contraseña1
            let passId = (e.target.name == 'password') ? 'Password2' : 'Password';
            testClasses(
                document.querySelector(`#Grupo__${passId}`),
                document.querySelector(`#Grupo__${passId} .formulario__validacion-estado`),
                test
            );
            break;

        case 'correo':

            break;

        case 'telefono':

            break;
    }
    testClasses(padre, icon, test);
}

function testClasses(padre, icon, test) {
    // Eliminar clases de padre
    padre.className = 'formulario__grupo';
    if(test) {
        padre.classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto');
        icon.classList.replace('fa-times-circle', 'fa-check-circle');
    } else {
        padre.classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
        icon.classList.replace('fa-check-circle', 'fa-times-circle');
    }
}

inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('keyup', validarFormulario);
    input.addEventListener('blur', validarFormulario);
});
```

```css
.fa-check-circle {
    color:#0a0;
}
.formulario__grupo-correcto { background:#fff; }
.formulario__grupo-incorrecto { background:#fcc; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-YSdqvJoZr83hj76AIVdOcvLWYMWzy6sJyIMic2aQz5kh2bPTd9dzY3NtdeEAzPp/PhgZqr4aJObB3ym/vsItMg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main>
<form id="Formulario" class="formulario">
    <!--Grupo Usuario-->
    <div id="Grupo__Usuario" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="usuario" class="formulario__label">Usuario</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="formulario__input" placeholder="Fernando123">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El usuario tiene que ser de 4 a 16 dígitos y solo puede contener numeros, letras y guion bajo</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Nombre-->
    <div id="Grupo__Nombre" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="nombre" class="formulario__label">Nombre</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="formulario__input" placeholder="John Doe">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El nombre tiene que ser de 4 a 16 dígitos y solo puede contener numeros, letras y guion bajo</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Contraseña-->
    <div id="Grupo__Password" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="password" class="formulario__label">Contraseña</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="formulario__input">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">La contraseña tiene que ser 4 a 12 digitos</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Contraseña-->
    <div id="Grupo__Password2" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="password2" class="formulario__label">Repetir Contraseña</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" class="formulario__input">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">Ambas contraseñas tienen que ser iguales</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Correo Electronico-->
    <div id="Grupo__Correo" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="correo" class="formulario__label">Correo Eléctronico</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="correo" id="correo" class="formulario__input" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El correo solo puede contener letras,numeros, punto y guines</p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Telefono-->
    <div id="Grupo__Telefono" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label for="telefono" class="formulario__label">Telefono</label>
        <div class="formulario__grupo-input">
            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" class="formulario__input" placeholder="554589634">
            <i class="formulario__validacion-estado fas fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="formulario__input-error">El teléfono solo úede contener numeros y el máximo es de 14 dígitos
        </p>
    </div>

    <!--Grupo Terminos y Condiciones-->
    <div id="Grupo__Terminos" class="formulario__grupo">
        <label class="formulario__label">
            <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos" class="formulario__checkbox">
            Acepto los Terminos y Condiciones
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="formulario__mensaje" id="formulario__mensaje">
        <p>
            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><b>Error:</b> Por favor rellena el formulario correctamente
        </p>
    </div>

    <div class="formulario__grupo formulario__grupo-btn-enviar">
        <button type="submit" class="formulario__btn">
            Enviar
        </button>
        <p class="formulario__mensaje-exito" id="formulario__mensaje-exito">
            Los datos se enviaron con éxito
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Nota:** Hice algunas modificaciones para evitar repetir código en cada comprobación:

- Crear variables para:

  - padre: Cambiar clase del contenedor
  - icon: Cambiar clase del icono
  - test: Verdadero o falso, de acuerdo a valor del campo
- Validar *password* y *password2* en el mismo bloque
- Crear función para aplicar los cambios: Es necesaria solo porque al teclear contraseñas, probablemente convenga actualizar el estado de los dos campos

Comment: El objetivo es cambiar iconos pasar de `fa-times-circle` a `fa-check-circle`

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Lo más fácil seria trabajar con `svg` en lugar de `i`?

Comment: @FernyCortez, técnicamente sí, pero se accede por medio de la clase porque el `svg` la mantiene.